# Binding empty values to numerical fields in Play Framework 2 (Java)

Tags: java, forms, playframework-2.0, databinder

I have forms where I want to be able to leave some numerical fields empty, but I get "Invalid value" errors from `Form.bindFromRequest()`. This seems like a common requirement, but I can't find any documentation on this after hours of searching. I am still hoping I've missed something obvious, though!

I did some digging and found that Play uses Spring's `DataBinder` class to do the actual binding. That class is really sophisticated and would allow me to set custom binders for my fields, and if I was using Spring I could just add an `@InitBinder` method to my controller to set up the binder exactly the way I want using a `CustomNumberEditor`. However, it seems that Play Framework's `Form` object does not allow access to the DataBinder, apart from setting allowed fields. So, the binder tries to convert an empty string into a long, which gives a `NumberFormatException`:

```
Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long' 
for property 'unitPriceExVAT'; 
nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

So, is there some other way of getting the binder to allow empty numerical fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your fields as `Long` instead of the `long` primitive type and the empty values will be treated as `null`.

Comment: Haha, amazing :). I knew it couldn't be as complicated as I was making it! Case errors like that are nearly impossible to find on your own sometimes. Thanks for helping out – it worked perfectly of course!